# Skyfield and apparent diameter

Tags: skyfield

Can Skyfield calculate the apparent diameter of a planet, the Sun or Moon?

Something along the lines of:

place.at(utc).observe(moon).apparent().angular_diameter

Answer (score 2):

You can work out the apparent diameter if you know the object's radius, with simple trigonometry:

```
from numpy import arcsin
MOON_RADIUS = 1737.1 # km
appdiam = 360 / pi * arcsin(MOON_RADIUS / place.at(utc).observe(moon).distance().km)
```

Comment: convert from rad to deg with 180/pi

Comment: Hi Adam.  We want the apparent diameter, not the radius, so it's 2*180/pi.  Try it with a typical moon distance of 384400km.  The expected result is around half a degree.